# windows + number with numeric pad

Tags: windows-10, keyboard-shortcuts, keypad

I'm looking for how to use Win + number shortcut to open programs using the numeric pad instead of the qwerty keys. Using Windows 10 I'm really used to having my high runner apps pinned to the task bar and use the "win + #" shortcut to open them but for some reason I can't use this with the numeric keypad numbers of the wired keyboard (numlock or not). Not sure if this is programmed behavior from windows or an actual keyboard setting. I prefer using keypad instead of qwerty numbers just because of hand placement. Any ideas hot to enable or workaround?

Comment: If you don't ever use the numeric keypad for cursor control, i.e. you only use it for numeric input, you can remap the keys to send the scancodes of the QWERTY numbers. If you want to do this, I can post the PowerShell to do so.

Comment: That does sound like a good workaround thank you. Will this also work for any plug n play keyboard?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work for plug 'n' play or built-in keyboards. Copy & paste this code into an ***Administrator*** PowerShell window (**Winkey+X** > **Windows PowerShell (Admin)**). The script is designed so that remap pairs can be easily added or subtracted. But as posted, it remaps the keys affected by Numlock (0-9, ./Del) to generate the scancodes of the corresponding QWERTY keys.

---

### Edit#2: Reworked code -- Same result, just tighter code.

```
###   *** This code must be run from an elevated (Admin) PowerShell session *** ###

###   If both source and target are not extended scan codes, 
###   add them here and the extended bytes will be added by code.

[Byte[]]$SimplePairs = @(
    0x02, 0x4f   #   [1 !] => [1 end]
    0x03, 0x50   #   [2 @] => [2 ↓]
    0x04, 0x51   #   [3 #] => [3 pg-dn]
    0x05, 0x4b   #   [4 $] => [4 ←]
    0x06, 0x4c   #   [5 %] => [5]
    0x07, 0x4d   #   [6 ^] => [6 →]
    0x08, 0x47   #   [7 &] => [7 home]
    0x09, 0x48   #   [8 *] => [8 ↑]
    0x0a, 0x49   #   [9 (] => [9 pg-up]
    0x0b, 0x52   #   [0 )] => [0 Ins]
    0x34, 0x53   #   [. >] => [. Del]
#   0x00, 0x3a   #   [Null] => [CapsLock]
).ForEach({ $_ , 0 })      ### Add zero-valued extended byte to each scancode

###   If either one or both are extended scan codes,
###   add them here with the extended byte value as well.

[Byte[]]$ExtendedPairs = @(
#   0x5d, 0xe0, 0x1d, 0xe0 # [ContextMenu] > [R-Ctrl]
)

[Byte[]]$AllPairs = $SimplePairs + $ExtendedPairs

[byte[]]$Remap    = [byte[]]::new(8) +  
                    [BitConverter]::GetBytes( $AllPairs.Length/4 + 1 ) +
                    $AllPairs +
                    [byte[]]::new(4)

$Splat = @{
    'Path'  = 'HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Keyboard Layout'
    'Name'  = 'ScanCode Map'
    'Value' = $Remap
    'Force' = $True
}
[Void]New-ItemProperty @Splat

echo @'


   ***   Done. Computer must be restarted   ***
   ***   before changes will take effect.   ***

'@
```

Once pasted, press  to execute & then restart the computer.

---

### Edit: Undo:

Using `RegEdit`, delete the `ScanCode Map` entry (type: `REG_BINARY`) from the registry key:

- `HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Keyboard Layout`

or run this command from an *Admin* **PowerShell** console:

- `Remove-ItemProperty 'HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Keyboard Layout' 'ScanCode Map'`

---

Bonus tip: If you need to temporarily disable remapping or experiment with differnet remappings, rename the regisry entry to something other than `ScamCode Map` and restart. Values with mames other than `ScamCode Map` are ignored:

[image]

Comment: How can I undo this once done?

Comment: Delete the `ScanCode Map` entry created by the script.

Comment: from the registry no?

Comment: Yes. I've edited the answer to include instructions to undo.