# How to disable Numlock permanently on Windows?

Tags: windows, windows-10, bios, windows-registry, numlock

I have tried some approaches as shown below to disable numlock **permanently** on my Windows machine, but none of them is working:

https://technoresult.com/how-to-disable-num-lock-completely-in-windows-10-11/

I also tried to use some 3rd party tools, but I don't want to use them as they are not working properly all the time.

There are some keymaps for registry, but I could not apply that map as it is not explained for beginners :(

So, how can I disable it?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Edit your question to clarify. Do you want the numeric keypad always typing numbers or always functioning as cursor control? Have you seen my anser [here](https://superuser.com/a/1467030/881098)? If you have Admin rights and can copy, paste, and press `<Enter>`, you can run the script.

Comment: @KeithMiller You'll need to way a couple of days more for some feedback if it ever comes.

Comment: @KeithMiller Yes, **I want the numeric keypad always typing numbers**. Any idea?

Comment: @ChanganAuto What are you trying to explain automatic?

Comment: @gustavo No, I was explaining to Keith he'd need to wait a few days for some feedback because you were suspended :) (and soon to be again with rude comments like that)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you could disable the key using a program such as key tweak.

```
1. Download and launch KeyTweak.

2. Select the key that you want to disable.

3. Under the Keyboard Controls section, select Disable Key.

4. Click on Apply.
```

https://www.makeuseof.com/tag/disable-specific-keys-keyboard-windows-10/

This article gives a step by step guide on how to disable a particular key.

Comment: Fascinasting!... Thanks a alot @Aydan.